# How to wait for operation to complete in azure blob service

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, express, azure-blob-storage

How to use async/await on blob service. I am trying download and zip folder and hence want to wait untill download completes, so that I can go ahead and zip that file.but due to async behaviour sometime function misbehaveing.

Latest code:

```
            const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString("connect string");
             
            const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
            
            for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat({ prefix: path })) {
              
           if (fs.existsSync(fileUploadPath)) {
            var sourceFilePath = fileUploadPath + '/' + project.id + '/' + blob.name;
            if (!fs.existsSync(sourceFilePath)) {
                fs.mkdir(require('path').dirname(sourceFilePath), { recursive: true }, async(err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Failed to mkdir:" + err);
                    }
                    console.log(blob.name)
                  await containerClient.getBlobClient(blob.name).downloadToFile(sourceFilePath,0,undefined);
                 
                });
            }
        } else{
        console.log('downloads folder does not configures!')
    }
```

I have a couple of doubts here,

1. How efficient is downloadToFile? can it download large sized blobs?
2. only immediate blob is downloaded that too with incomplete data and blobs under subdirectory are not being downloaded.
3. I thought , streaming data is efficient way to download blobs?is there any API to stream data to local, like we had one in old library (getBlobToStream)?

Comment: Here is a PowerShell example of how i tackled it.
`While($memStream.Length -ne $memStream.Capacity){...}`

Answer (score 3):

Using the latest version of the [Azure Storage Blob SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/sdk/storage/storage-blob), you could convert your existing code to something like that:

```js
const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const account = "<account>";
const accountKey = "<accountkey>";

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  sharedKeyCredential
);

const containerName = '<container name>';
const path = '<prefix>';

async function download() {
  var containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat({ prefix: path })) {
    await containerClient.getBlobClient(blob.name)
      .downloadToFile(`./${blob.name}`);
  }
}

download()
  .then(() => console.log('Done'))
  .catch((ex) => console.log(ex.message));
```

Comment: I have updated to new library but dont see blobs under subdirectory.

Comment: in my example i use `listBlobsFlat` which return flat path. which method are you using ?

Comment: I used the same method, and it lists all the blobs as expected but next it does not download all the blobs to my local.

Comment: @sd this that work for you ?