# EMFILE: too many open files, azure blob service error

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

While trying to get all the blobs in specified path to local using getblobtostream() in azure blob service, I am getting following error, How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and error as text, not as a cropped image.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is enumerating all of the blobs in the container, then opening the local files simultaneously and starting to download them. (`forEach` is unaware of asynchronous code. (On that note, without seeing the rest of your code, I'd reckon you also have a bug in that sense, since you can't know when all of those downloads are complete.))

That's why you're bumping into the open file limit of your OS – but you'd also bump into bandwidth and request limit issues.

I'd recommend refactoring your code to use `async`/`await` instead of callback-style asynchronicity (as you were pointed towards in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72362594/51685), and then using e.g. the `p-queue` or `p-limit` packages to limit the concurrency of those blob downloads.